# Django Static Files - what am I missing?

Tags: python, django

need some help with why static files aren't showing up.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.  I believe I followed the steps correctly at the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/).

Here are the steps I am taking with Django version 1.6.1

```
$ django-admin.py startproject django_test_static
$ cd django_test_static
$ ./manage.py startapp testapp
$ mkdir -p testapp/static/testapp
$ echo "hi there" > testapp/static/testapp/test.txt
$ ./manage.py runserver
```

Then when I attempt to retrieve the file, it doesn't work:

```
[26/Jan/2014 17:05:40] "GET /static/testapp/test.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 1652
```

1.6.1 comes pre-loaded with the `django.contrib.staticfiles` and `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`.

I'm doing something wrong.  What?!

Comment: Have you set DEBUG to True (see django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).?

Comment: Yes - am using the default installation.  No changes other that what I displayed via the command line.  `django.contrib.staticfiles` is included.

Comment: Have a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223884/html-background-image/21224602#21224602) to a previous question. Go through that checklist to catch anything obvious.

Comment: Can you post your `urls.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If in fact these are the only changes that you have made to your project then you are missing one important step: adding `testapp` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

The default `STATICFILES_FINDERS` uses `FileSystemFinder` and `AppDirectoriesFinder`. The `FileSystemFinder` looks for files in the `STATICFILES_DIRS`. This defaults to an empty tuple so Django won't find `test.txt` this way. The `AppDirectoriesFinder` looks inside of the `static` directories inside of each of the `INSTALLED_APPS`. If you haven't added `testapp` Django won't know to look there.

There seems to be an awful lot of confusion about how Django finds static files but it is nearly identical to how it finds templates: `STATICFILES_FINDERS` ~= `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` and `STATICFILES_DIRS` ~= `TEMPLATE_DIRS`.

Comment: That's why it wasn't working in the test case - thanks.  I knew I was missing something basic.  Geez.  *head palm*