# Django staticfiles

Tags: django, openshift, django-staticfiles, paas, static-files

I'm struggling getting staticfiles (CSS) to work on my Django site deployed to Openshift. I can workaround this by  putting style info in the HTML templates, but the Django admin site stylesheets still will not load. Everything works locally, including with debug off.

Openshift stores staticfilesunder repo/ -> wsgi/ -> static/, where the main project directory is also under wsgi/.

Here are the relevant parts of settings.py:

```
ON_OPENSHIFT = True if 'OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR' in os.environ else False
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), os.pardir)

if ON_OPENSHIFT:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'wsgi', 'static')
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

if ON_OPENSHIFT:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'wsgi', 'static'))
else:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')]
```

I have a script that runs the following when deploying:

```
cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/wsgi/squadron
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

I'm using Python 3.3 and Django 1.6, and referencing the following guides: [1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/deployment/) and [2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/) from the docs.

What am I doing wrong? I don't get an error message, just no stylesheets, either my own, or on Django admin. When I use SCP, I can verify my stylesheet is in the correct Openshift directory.

Comment: What are your settings for STATICFILES_FINDERS and STATICFILES_STORAGE? Just to discount any easy fixes, work your way through my answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21224602/1407227). Also, your first reference to STATICFILES_DIRS needs a trailing comma between the two closing parentheses:`STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'], 'wsgi', 'static'),)` or it won't be interpreted as a tuple, which of course you do want it to be.

Comment: Thanks - fixed the comma issue. STATICFILES_FINDERS is default, with ...FileSystemFinder and ...AppDirectoriesFinder selected. STATICFILES_STORAGE is not present, so it's at its default value of ...StaticFilesStorage. Great tutorial in your link, but mine's set properly according to it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the best source to read when you are trying to get OpenShift working with Django.

http://appsembler.com/blog/django-deployment-using-openshift/

Some of this will be changing (for the better) with upcoming releases but this should help for now.