# Django static files not loading (production)

Tags: django

I can not see my static files when running the project on the server (at my desktop it was ok).

When I look for the picture path on my browser I have

```
/static/app_name/images/image_name
```

My images are stored at

```
www.mydomain.com/xxx/xxx/static/app_name/images/image_name
```

I tried to adjust the settings.py from

```
'/static/'
```

to

```
'/xxx/xxx/static/'
```

But it seems to have no effect as the images path on my browser are still

```
/static/app_name/images/image_name and not /xxx/xxx/static/app_name/images/image_name
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Common reasons for this addressed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21224602/1407227) - have you ruled those out?

Comment: I have tried all of them when I was able... but the issue seems to be as S.Ali pointed out... but the changes I make in settings.py they do not get reflected in the path of the image in my browser...

Comment: After changes do restart you server. And did that work out!!

Comment: @user2950162 did changing path to what i suggested worked out for you?

Answer (score 2):

Changing `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` is only going to change the URL, not where the images are actually served.

Make sure that `STATIC_ROOT` is pointing to `/path/to/www.mydomain.com/xxx/xxx/static/` and make sure you **are** using hard-coded paths in your `settings.py`, *not* something like

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__, 'static'))
```

Then in your templates

```
<!-- either -->
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/my_image.png" />
<!-- or -->
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'img/my_image.png' %}" />
```

Also, be sure you're running `python manage.py collectstatic` to collect all of the static files from all of your apps to place them in the `STATIC_ROOT` directory.

#### Also

Depending on which server you're using, make sure you have a path alias that points to your static directory. For example, in Apache in your /sites-available/www.mydomain.com conf make sure that this `Alias` directive exists

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    Alias /static /path/to/www.mydomain.com/xxx/xxx/static/
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```